# Function Error (Fatal error: Function name must be a string)

Tags: php, function

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/auth.php');
    function getMarkets(){
        $count_markets=querydb("SELECT count(*) as marketcount from markets ");
        $result=$count_markets('marketcount');
        return $result;
    }
```

I have the above code and i am getting the error below:
Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Comment: What is the return type of `querydb(string)`? A function or a array?

Comment: Whatever `querydb` returns isn't a string (could be an array, object or integer since the query itself is `COUNT(*)`) - and you're attempting to assign that value to being a function name `$count_markets=querydb(...); ... $count_markets('marketcount');` - if you're going to use a variable function name, it has to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Seen the Error was using `$count_markets('marketcount');` instead of `$count_markets['marketcount'];`

Comment: Haha, nobody thinks about it - everybody assumes that You are trying to incorrectly call a method :D

Comment: true i laughed when i saw the error. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

`$result=$count_markets('marketcount');` - remove `$` from `count_markets`.

Comment: why are you so sure the problem is that and not the fact that `querydb` was meant to return a string corresponding to the function that needs to be called?

Comment: ok querydb  runs  a mysqli_fetch_array here's how i defined it <br> 
function querydb($query)
{
    
    $result1=querydb($query);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $result;
    exit;
}

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - even if `querydb` returned the specific result from the query, in this instance it would be invalid since it's a `COUNT(*)` query and you can't have a function name like `37()`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Whatever man - his problem is that he don't use correct method name. I assume that there is a method called `count_markets()` - named as this variable. If he made what I wrote, he will have different error which indicates him, that there is no such method

Comment: @bigwolk see [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: @CD001 - I know that there is something like that (but IMO using this will kill You later or sooner - debuging will be horrible), but not from `count` query which should return a number :|

Comment: Seen the Error was casting  $count_markets('marketcount'); instead of $count_markets['marketcount'];

Comment: @CD001 seeing OP answered his own question, this point in moot, but, that's why I said *"`querydb` was meant to return a string corresponding to the function that needs to be called"*. I could have been a bit more clear, but the sense was "the problem is with the query". As I said, the point is moot since that was not the problem anyway, just wanted to let you know I was aware of it :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I thought you meant the problem was with the function (in what it returned) rather than the query specifically - the result would be the same though so I was kind of agreeing with you in a roundabout way ;)